# Как расположить блок при адаптиве?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать это, я не делал ещё подобного адаптива. Сложновато от незнания. )

Что сделать с блоком (тот что с низу с текстом) что-бы он находился всегда на одном уровне?
В розовой области это то, как нужно. На разных устройствах он ездит то выше, то ниже. Это проблема моя.
Шапку я поставил на *position: fixed;* она должна быть всегда.
Кнопку так-же на *position: fixed;* она должна быть на расстоянии от блока с текстом.
А этот блок с текстом на *position: absolute;*

По идее когда я начинаю скролить в низ, кнопка должна остаться на месте.
А вот этот длинный блок с текстом может уезжать в верх. (шапка обретает белый цвет и он под неё укатывается).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я тут пример кода накидал

```css
body {
  overflow-X: hidden;
}
.box {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.head {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.center {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
.box_text {
  position: relative;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.box_link {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.link {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  width: 208px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f08b9891;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 0;
}
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.wrap {
  flex: 1;
}
.img {
  background-image: url(https://sun9-40.userapi.com/xjTDHjGgBeTSRSCLGGxEfxIjpjZwMDqrdnXoMw/ImCKCCXvj6M.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
      display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.menu_text {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    max-width: 663px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.item_link {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    transition: 0.1s;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.item_image {
   background-image: url(https://sun9-73.userapi.com/PkzUW9XXy2w4Oof1LQOwvY9B3ftnDXJUcqezMA/t7FU55t8RMI.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="box">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="head"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="center">
            <div class="box_text">Аниме бложек</div>
            <div class="box_link">
                <a href="#" class="link">Кликай меня</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="menu_text">
            Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="item_link">
                <div class="item_image"></div>
                Далеко-далеко
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="item_link">
                <div class="item_image"></div>
                Далеко-далеко
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="item_link">
                <div class="item_image"></div>
                Далеко-далеко
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="item_link">
                <div class="item_image"></div>
                Далеко-далеко
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="item_link">
                <div class="item_image"></div>
                Далеко-далеко
              </a>
            </li>            <li>
              <a href="#" class="item_link">
                <div class="item_image"></div>
                Далеко-далеко
              </a>
            </li>            <li>
              <a href="#" class="item_link">
                <div class="item_image"></div>
                Далеко-далеко
              </a>
            </li>            <li>
              <a href="#" class="item_link">
                <div class="item_image"></div>
                Далеко-далеко
              </a>
            </li>            <li>
              <a href="#" class="item_link">
                <div class="item_image"></div>
                Далеко-далеко
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="img"></div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' , Я вчера еще заходил сюда, вчитывался во все это. Тоже самое. "**Ничего не понял, но очень интересно**". Хотел написать комментарий, но решил что подожду, пока кто-нибудь другой ответит. А оказывается я и не один такой))

Comment: Да я уже почти сделал его ) Нужно было чтобы блок с текстом был всегда на одном уровне и не выезжал ни выше ни ниже если менять разрешение экрана (использовать разные устройства). Тоже самое я сейчас написал, что и в описании только другими словами )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было сделать один общий бокс для главного экрана.

```
position: relative;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
```

В него положить отдельные блоки "по категориям" шапка, центральная часть и блок с товарами "где рыбный текст".
Для первых двух блоков указать `flex: 1;` у последнего блока `flex: 0;`
У шапки своя высота указана в стилях (она выделена зелёным) а если смотреть по *flex: 1* она занимает одну треть экрана.

Блоку с товарами "где рыбный текст" состоит из основного блока у которого  `flex: 0;` и в нём лежат два блока. 1й это "рыбный текст", 2й это товары. У этих двух блоков `position: relative;`.
Обоим блокам задать нужную высоту, тогда мы будем иметь нужную высоту для блока "рыбный текст" и нужную высоту, то на сколько будет выглядывать с низу блок с товарами, остальная его часть будет скрыта ниже.``
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]